# How to make each page of PageView a URL to link, share and index on Google?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I would like to create a blog in Flutter for Web with a PageView showing the articles one at a time.
The problem is that every article must be shareable and indexable by Google, so every page of PageView must have its url.

What I thought was to dynamically change the url by adding the article's id every time the user changes page.
Ex.

```
www.beautifulsite.com/articles + ?id=1234
```

In this way, if a user arrives on the site with the modified URL, I can go back to the article and then display it directly on the page number desired.
However, Google would not be able to index the articles, is it not?

Design example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kA2mO.png

Comment: Are those articles displayed into a `ListView()`?

Comment: No, `PageView()`, in order to keep track of page number and center the article

Comment: Just having a look at its documentation, you see that `PageController()` has a `keepPage:` method, maybe you could try this.

Comment: On mobile i use a `SnapList` for another project, could it be better? [here](http://47.75.70.92/packages/snaplist/versions/0.1.4)

Comment: I can't tell if that would be better, but using PageView is a way to go, and you can track the Article with the `keepPage:` method. I hadn't tried using SnapList before, so I can't give you any advice on this, sorry.

Comment: Would Google be able to index articles if I dynamically change the URL?